# How to add custom message in to my form mailer

Tags: php

I want to add "This message came from etcetc.com" in the e-mail form in the e-mail body itself. Hope this make sense..

my sent_email.php

```
<?php
$email_to = 'test@test.org'; 
$name = $_POST['name'];  
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
if(mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'sent'; // we are sending this text to the ajax request telling it that the mail is sent..      
} else {
    echo 'failed'; // ... or this one to tell it that it wasn't sent    
}
```

?>

Comment: And what is the problem you've encountered?

Comment: Consider appending to `$message`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
<?php
$email_to = 'test@test.org'; 
$name = $_POST['name'];  
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = "This message came from etcetc.com \r\n".$_POST['message'];

$headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
if(mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'sent'; // we are sending this text to the ajax request telling it that the mail is sent..      
} else {
    echo 'failed'; // ... or this one to tell it that it wasn't sent    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add your text to the end of `$message`.

Change:

`$message = $_POST['message'];`

to

`$message = $_POST['message'] . "\n\nThis message came from etcetc.com";`

Answer (score 0):

Add message before and after as you wish by

```
$message = "This is before posted message\r\n";
$message .= $_POST["message"];
$message .= "\r\nthis is after the posted message";
```